# Set delegate for a custom UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, uinavigationbar

I am trying to add custom elements including drop downs and view changing from my `navigationBar`, because of this I need a custom one. However when trying to set the delegate to my view controller it throws an error.

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <MyCustomNavigationBarDelegate>

@implementation MyViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithNavigationBarClass:[MyCustomNavigationBar class] toolbarClass:[UIToolbar class]];
    nav.navigationBar.assessmentDelegate = self;
}
```

The last line throws the error Property '`assessmentDelegate`' not found on object of type '`UINavigationBar` *' However it should be type of class `MyCustomNavigationBar` which clearly has the delegate:

```
@protocol MyCustomNavigationBarDelegate;

@interface MyCustomNavigationBar : UINavigationBar

@property (weak, nonatomic) id <MyCustomNavigationBarDelegate> assessmentDelegate;

@end

@protocol MyCustomNavigationBarDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)presentViewController:(UIAlertController *)alert;

@end
```

Comment: Your question seems reasonable, if a tad naive, so I upvoted it.

Comment: Be aware that the method `initWithNavigationBarClass` that you're using is likely to make your life difficult. The docs say "To customize the overall appearance of a navigation bar, use UIAppearance APIs instead of this method. If you use this initialization method to create a navigation bar that uses custom bar subclasses, you are responsible for pushing and setting view controllers before presenting the navigation controller onscreen."  So it sounds like you gain the burden of a fair amount of additional housekeeping when using this method.

Comment: Thanks yeah I switched it out for the code Shubhank left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cast your navigaton Bar to `MyCustomNavigationBar`

```
MyCustomNavigationBar  *switchNav = (MyCustomNavigationBar *)nav.navigationBar;
switchNav.assessmentDelegate = self
```

Comment: Thanks would love to know why I was downvoted, but this worked great!

Comment: yup, dont know why it was downvoted. Good question, i did my upvote.